# Debugging a Spring MVC application running on Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am asking the correct way of debugging a Dynamic Web Application in Eclipse.

I have two sort of files: 
the view: jsp
the controller: Spring Controller

When I changed a jsp file, whether in debug mode or not, the change will be reflected seamlessly.
But whether in debug mode or not, if i change controller's content, all the application will be redeployed to tomcat. Even some time, the tomcat fails to redeploy (restart).

Is there a more appropriate way to debug such an application?

Comment: Is your server started in debug mode?

Comment: Yes. I'm starting the server in debug mode. I can debug my application. But I cannot change anything on the controller without redeploying (I'm not sure the process is redeploying. I call it that way) . I stated this in the problem statement: The view changes always visible whether in debug or run mode.  The controller changes require a (automatic) redeploy even in debug mode. I understand partially. I'm using Hibernate. If I change a dao structure, it should restart. But changing the controller logic, i think, should not require a restart.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681679/why-tomcat-does-not-require-restart-when-jsp-is-changed

Answer (score 0):

What JDK implementation are you using? I had a similar problem when using the standard Sun HotSpot JDK 1.6. It was fixed when I switched to using JRockit JDK. I believe Oracle plans to integrate these two implementations in the foreseeable future.

Comment: I'm using Oracle JDK 1.7 with Eclipse Juno. Tomcat version is 7. I'm starting the server with Debug.